# Uplaod an Image file from React to Rails server

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, form-data

I am trying to upload and send a simple image file to my Rails 7 API using FormData from React as I read it is only right to use that while uploading a file.
this is what my code looks like

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

      
    const data = Object.fromEntries(formData)
    dispatch(createAsset(data)); //this a redux function
    e.currentTarget.reset()
   
  };
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={toggleForm && 'hide-form'}>
   <div>
     <label>Property Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
   </div> 
   <div>
   <labal>image upload</labal>
   <input type="file" name="image" />
   </div>
   <button className="btn" type="submit"> create assets</button>
</form>
HTTP request is made
```

the other field hit the rails console with values except the image_field which shows an empty object in the rails console (when I try to debug I see an image object in the React debugging). I would love to know if I'm doing something wrong and why the image_field sends an empty image object to my Rails app.

```
const createAsset = createAsyncThunk('asset/create_asset', async (data) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}assets`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token()}`,

    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return response;
});
```

this is the rails controller action

```
 def create
    @asset = Asset.new(asset_params)

    if @asset.save
      render json: @asset, status: :created
    else
      render json: @asset.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

def asset_params
      params.require(:asset).permit(:name, :image)
    end
```

asset modal

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :image
      def image_url 
        # Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(image, only_path: true)
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image) if image.attached?

      
    end
    
end
```

PS: I did not detail the rails setup as I strongly believe the issue is from the React code

Comment: Please update and include your HTTP request logic and, just to be sure, please include your rails controller method (where you expect to receive the upload). I assume the issue is in your HTTP request.

Comment: done that already

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your JS code is how you format the data before sending the request:

```js
'Content-type': 'application/json'
```

You're transmitting the data in JSON format, which is the incorrect format when handling file uploads. What you should be using is this encoding type:

```js
'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

You can set this in your `fetch` config, **BUT** the recommended way to do it is to declare it in the form element via the [enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#enctype) attribute:

```html
<form
  className={toggleForm && 'hide-form'}
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  method="post"
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
  <!-- Elements here -->
</form>
```

To quote from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Using_FormData_Objects):

> **Warning:** When using `FormData` to submit POST requests using `XMLHttpRequest` or the `Fetch API` with the `multipart/form-data` content type (e.g. when uploading files and blobs to the server), *do not* explicitly set the `Content-Type` header on the request. Doing so will prevent the browser from being able to set the `Content-Type` header with the boundary expression it will use to delimit form fields in the request body.

So, before you send the request, make sure that you're passing the `FormData` object directly. Here's your updated fetch logic:

```js
const createAsset = createAsyncThunk('asset/create_asset', async (data) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}assets`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token()}`,
    },
    body: data, // `FormData` object
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return response;
});
```

Comment: i did thes an more but it seems like it doesn't hit the rails server with the data.
i am getting this `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: asset):`

Comment: this was helpful. thank you. i wasn't initially passing the formData directly

Answer (score 0):

What if

- you use `multipart/form-data` as `content-type` for your request?
- you pass your body using `FormData`?

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('post[name]', name)
formData.append('post[image]', image)

// set `body: formData` in your request
```

Reference:

- https://hackernoon.com/how-to-upload-an-image-from-react-to-the-rails-api-using-react-hook-form-and-context-api
- https://github.com/tonystrawberry/matomeishi-next.jp/blob/main/app/cards/new/page.tsx#L145 (sample from one of my personal projects)

Comment: this was helpful. thank you